# Scripting a routine SCP from a shared access server at my work to my personal server. What's the best way?

Tags: shell-script, python, scp

I got the sysadmin at my work to set up a Cron job on the local server, which routinely runs a Python script I wrote.

Basically, pulls some data off the local intranet, does some magic on it and presents the results in HTML form. I'm able to SSH into the work server and modify my scripts, and anybody in the organisation can access them and any other files in the directory.

I'd like for my script to SCP the final HTML file to my personal web server (any directory is fine) so that I can view its output when I'm not at work. What would be the best way to do this? I've had a few ideas but I want to make sure I do it the right way, i.e. by not dumping my personal credentials on to the work server for everyone to see.

NB. the internal data that the script uses is all available publicly, albeit in a more difficult to work with format, so I don't believe there is an ethical issue here.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. You say you want a script to SCP the final HTML to your personal web server. Is this the same script that is run by CRON to collate the data and place it on the webserver?

Comment: Maybe you could do it from the other point of view. I mean, by running the `scp` command from your personal server against the work server to get the files.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1.

On your personal PC, use `ssh-keygen` to create an authentication key for your home PC. This will allow your script at "work" to upload the file to your home PC without a login.

Amend your script to upload the HTML file to your home PC using your your login.

Option 2.

Amend your script (at work) to output the HTML to a public web space and simply view it in a browser.